# Download files from network shared folder using angular

Tags: angular

I have a network shared folder (\server\folder) and I need to download files (*.zip extension) using angular. I found some resources that may help in downloading files from by doing that using rest api, but they didn't help. The requirement is to download them (directly from the network shared folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service you could do something like that to avoid the JSON response

```
public getFile(): Observable<Blob> {   
//const options = { responseType: 'blob' }; there is no use of this
    let uri = '/your/uri'; 
    return this.http.get(uri, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}
```

And inside your Component you can download your file ('ZIP') as follow :

```
public downloadZIP(): void {
  this.yourService.downloadFile(filename).subscribe(data => {
  const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'application/zip'
  });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
});
}
```

In your RESTController you can have something that looks like :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/downloadZipFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadZIPfile(@RequestParam(value = "zipFileName") String zipFileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String sharedFolderUri ="path_to_the_shared_folder/"+zipFileName+".zip";
            File zipFile = new File(sharedFolderUri );
Path path = Paths.get(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                System.out.println("File Name :" + zipFile.getName());
                InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(zipFile));

         return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(zipFile.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .body(resource);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your response. But, can you please provide a c# code instead of the above RESTController. I'm using Asp.Net Web.Api.